# What is the reason for the "inputs" property of a component in an Angular 2 app?

Tags: angular

From the docs,

'The input declaration ensures that consumers of our directive can only bind to the properties of our public API ... nothing else.'

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#why-input

This is not super clear. I'm not really sure *why* we need to define this at all. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

`@Input() someInput;` (or `@Component({inputs: ['someInput']})`) creates a property on your custom element you can bind to like

```
<my-component [someInput]="someField"></my-component>
```

Without the `@Input()` the binding wouldn't be allowed and you'd get an error message when loading the Angular application.

There are also other reasons for this declarative approach:

- It should allow tools to get meta information about your components

  - for syntax-checks
  - autocompletion
- Angular2 uses this meta information to generate code that hooks up the binding

  - for example `ngOnChanges()` is called when a binding to an input changes.

Comment: Ah info about metadata explains why the binding is necessary